# Proof of the tranformation formula for a probability density and its generalizations

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I want to prove the following tranformation formula for a probability density, where the tranformation can be many-to-one:

> Let $ (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) $ be a probability space and $ X:
>  \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n $ be an absolutely continuous random vector
> with a density $f_X$. Suppose $ \psi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $
> is a continuous map and there are open sets $ U_1, \dots, U_k
>  \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ such that:
>
> 1. $U_i \cap U_j = \emptyset$ for $1 \leq i < j \leq k$
> 2. the union $ U = U_1 \cup \dots \cup U_k $ has $P(X \in U) = 1$
> 3. $\psi$ is continuously differentiable on $U$
> 4. $D\psi(x)$ is invertible for all $x \in U$
> 5. each $\psi|_{U_i}$ is injective on $U_i$
>
> If $ Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n $ is the random vector $Y = \psi(X)$,
> then $Y$ is absolutely continuous with a density given by: $$ f_Y(y) =
>  \sum_{ x \in \psi^{-1}(y) \cap U } \frac{f_X(x)}{| \det D\psi(x) |}
>  \quad \text{for } y \in \psi(U) \\
>  \text{and} \quad f_Y(y) = 0
>  \quad \text{for } y \in \psi(U)^c $$

Below is my proof, assuming the change of variable formula.

**Proof:**

For each $i$, let $V_i = \psi(U_i)$ and $ \phi_i : V_i \to U_i $ be the inverse of $\psi|_{U_i}$.

By the inverse function theorem, each $\phi_i$ is a diffeomorphism, so $ D\phi_i(y) = D\psi(\phi_i(y))^{-1} $ for $y \in V_i$.

Let $A$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $ \psi^{-1}(A) \cap U_i = \phi_i(A \cap V_i) $. Thus,

\begin{align*}
P(Y \in A)
&= P(X \in \psi^{-1}(A)) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k P(X \in \psi^{-1}(A) \cap U_i) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k P(X \in \phi_i(A \cap V_i)) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \int_{\phi_i(A \cap V_i)} f_X(x) dx \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \int_{A \cap V_i} f_X(\phi_i(y)) |\det D\phi_i(y)| dy
\end{align*}

where the last line is by the change of variable formula.

Since $A$ is an arbitrary Borel set, by the almost everywhere uniqueness of density,

$$
f_Y(y) = \sum_{i=1}^k f_X(\phi_i(y)) |\det D\phi_i(y)| \mathbb{1}_{V_i}(y)
\quad \text{a.e.}
$$

If $y \in \psi(U)^c$, then $f_Y(y) = 0$.

On the other hand, if $y \in \psi(U)$, then

\begin{align*}
f_Y(y)
&= \sum_{i: y \in V_i} f_X(\phi_i(y)) |\det D\phi_i(y)| \\
&= \sum_{i: y \in \psi(U_i)} \frac{f_X(\phi_i(y))}{|\det D\psi(\phi_i(y))|} \\
&= \sum_{ x \in \psi^{-1}(y) \cap U } \frac{f_X(x)}{| \det D\psi(x) |}
\end{align*}

**Questions:**

1. Is my proof correct?
2. The condition in the theorem is quite cumblesome. Can the theorem be generalized to a simpler form? For example, does the result still hold if the condition is weaken to the following? If yes, could you provide a proof?

> Let $ (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) $ be a probability space and
> $ X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n $ be an absolutely continuous random vector
> with a density $f_X$. Suppose $ \psi: U \to \mathbb{R}^n $ is a **$C^1$ local**
> diffeomorphism on an open set $ U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ such that
> $ P(X \in U) = 1 $.

3. Can the condition above be further weaken to that $\psi$ is merely continuously differentiable on $U$ (so $D\psi$ can be singular)?
4. Is there a generalization of the theorem for a general random vector, not necessarily absolutely continuous?

Comment: This does not answer most of your questions, but: if the restriction is the applicability of the change-of-variable formula, there are more general change-of-variable formulas that are corollaries of the "area formula" and "co-area formula" from measure theory: see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Area_formula and https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Coarea_formula

Comment: This isn't really what you're asking, but I think I have used a special case of your formula here, Thm. 2: acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol43/vol43pp0597-0616.pdf

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Well, you can assume your family $U_i$ to be countable, which I believe is equivalent to the local diffeomorphism thing. Even if not equivalent, it's not too far away, and I don't think verifying the local diffeomorphism assumption would be any easier. And while the assumptions might seem cumbersome, they're in fact very natural. 3. If $D\psi$ is non-singular a.e., then yes. But in this case, you can remove the singularity points. 4. Not that I heard of.